# Two persons $A$ & $B$ toss a coin 50 times each together. Find the probability that both of them get 'tails' at the same time.

Tags: probability

For answer the following options are given:

1. $(2^{50}-51)/2^{100}$
2. $50/2^{100}$
3. $50^2/2^{50}$
4. $(2^{50}-1)/2^{100}$

Now 2 person throwing a coin 50 times each **together** is similar to a single person throwing 100 coins.

So, that person has 2 options (head or tail) for a single throw, so, for **100 throws** he has $2^{100}$ options. Thus, the **sample space** becomes $2^{100}$.

But, then I'm unable to find the **no of favorable cases** for this sum &  thus unable to find the required probability.

Comment: hint:  What's the probability that they fail to get TT on a single try? Given that, what's the probability that they fail to get TT 50 times in a row?

Comment: The problem is not clearly stated. Are we looking for that probability that they will obtain heads on the same try exactly once or at least once?

Comment: @ John McGee: The no of heads or tails that they should get is not mentioned in the question.I think we have to find the probability that if A gets a tail in his 'n'th throw (n<=50) then in the immediate next throw B will also get a tail [in his (n+1)th throw].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but if you take each flip of the two players as being a joint outcome single trial (so $50$ total trials, $4$ possible outcomes per trial), then the probability they don't BOTH get tails on a particular trial is $3/4$. Thus your probability should be $1 - (3/4)^{50}$ since $(3/4)^{50}$ is the probability that they never simultaneously get tails on the same flip. Not sure how this reconciles with your possible answer choices though.

Comment: Yes,nice..[1-(3/4)^50] = [(2^100-3^50)/2^100],so even if the numerator is somewhat different,the denominator seems to match, & as in the question it is given that they throw the coins simultaneously, i think your logic works.

Comment: That's why it's silly to get numerical answers in this form, unless they simply expect you to use one approach taught in class.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Yes I agree. I didn't take time to really study the given answer choices due to formatting issues, but I had a feeling that perhaps the way to see my proposed answer is indeed equal to one of the choices may require applying a non-trivial algebraic manipulation to my given answer to the question, which may be hard. But I was hoping someone else would post a comment on how to reconcile my answer with a chosen answer, or even better yet, post a solution that makes it obvious which choice is correct, totally circumventing my answer. If the latter happens, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @ user2566092:If you don't mind,can i ask u a silly question.In your answer you have taken the 'probability that they don't both get tails on a particular trial' & thus got the probability as:[1-(3/4)^50].But if i don't go by 'negation' & directly find out the 'probability that they always get tail on a particular trial i.e [1/4],then i get the answer as [(1/4)^50] i.e [1/(2^100)].Is this approach somehow right??& if not,can you please explain why.Sorry again for asking such a silly question.

Comment: @InfinitelyUndefined If we interpret the question your way (in one way to interpret your way), then indeed they must get tails at all the same times and get heads at all the same times. So the probability would be $(1/2)^{50}$ if the number of tails does not matter, otherwise it would be a bit different if we demand that there is at least one tails. If they all must be tails, then indeed $(1/2)^{100}$ is the answer

Comment: @user2566092: OK.I got your point.Thanks a lot for the elaboration & the answer.